# Delphi thread [Review my code]

Tags: multithreading, delphi

So my code does this:

1. Download page in thread
2. Parse the page
3. Send it to main thread

All that is done over critical section and postmessage .
IF anyone could review it fix it change it , or anything else that could make it better.

```
Main VCL form :

    unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, OverbyteIcsWndControl, OverbyteIcsHttpProt, StdCtrls,Unit2;
const
  WM_DATA_IN_BUF = WM_APP + 1000;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    HttpCli1: THttpCli;
    Button1: TButton;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FStringSectInit: boolean;
    FGoogle: TGoogle;
    FStringBuf: TStringList;
    procedure HandleNewData(var Message: TMessage); message WM_DATA_IN_BUF;
  public
     StringSection: TRTLCriticalSection;
    property StringBuf: TStringList read FStringBuf write FStringBuf;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not FStringSectInit then
  begin
    InitializeCriticalSection(StringSection);
    FStringBuf := TStringList.Create;
    FStringSectInit := true;
    FGoogle := TGoogle.Create(true);
    SetThreadPriority(FGoogle.Handle, THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL);
    try
      FGoogle.StartNum := 8;
    except
      on EConvertError do FGoogle.StartNum := 2;
    end;
    FGoogle.Resume;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.HandleNewData(var Message: TMessage);
var i:integer;
begin
  if FStringSectInit then
  if listbox1.Items.Count<10 then
  begin
    EnterCriticalSection(StringSection);
    for i:=0 to 5 do
    if length(fstringbuf.Text)>10 then
    begin
    listbox1.Items.Add(FStringBuf.Strings[i]);
    end
    else
    FStringBuf.Clear;
    LeaveCriticalSection(StringSection);
    {Now trim the Result Memo.}
  end
  else
  begin
    with FGoogle do
    begin
      Terminate;
      WaitFor;
      Free;
    end;
   FGoogle := nil;
    FStringBuf.Free;
    FStringBuf := nil;
    DeleteCriticalSection(StringSection);
    FStringSectInit := false;
  end;
end;
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if listbox1.Items.Count>80 then
end;

end.
```

And the Thread :

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Classes,Windows,IDHTTP, OverbyteIcsWndControl, StdCtrls,OverbyteIcsHttpProt,SysUtils,Dialogs;

type
  TGoogle = class(TThread)
  private
google:TStringList;
    Upit:string;
    Broj:integer;
    Buffer : TStringList;
  protected
    procedure parsegoogleapi;
    procedure SkiniSors;
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    property StartNum: integer read Broj write Broj;
  end;

implementation
uses unit1,StrUtils;

function ExtractText(const Str, Delim1, Delim2: string; PosStart: integer; var PosEnd: integer): string;
var
 pos1, pos2: integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    pos1 := PosEx(Delim1, Str, PosStart);
    if pos1 > 0 then
    begin
    pos2 := PosEx(Delim2, Str, pos1 + Length(Delim1));
    if pos2 > 0 then
    begin
      PosEnd := pos2 + Length(Delim2);
      Result := Copy(Str, pos1 + Length(Delim1), pos2 - (pos1 + Length(Delim1)));
end;
end;
end;
function ChangeString(const Value: string; replace:string): string;
var i: Integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    for i := 1 to Length(Value) do
    if Value[i] = ' ' then
    Result := Result + replace
    else
    Result := Result + Value[i]
end;

(*Ovo je procedura za skidanje sorsa*)

procedure TGoogle.SkiniSors;
var
HttpCli1 : THttpCli;
criter:string;

begin

HttpCli1:=THttpCli.Create(nil);
google:=TStringList.Create;
criter:= ChangeString(Upit,'%20');

With HttpCli1 do begin
    URL            := 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=' + inttostr(broj) + '&rsz=large&q=index.php';
    RequestVer     := '1.1';
    RcvdStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
        Get;
    except
        ShowMessage('There has been an error , check your internet connection !');
        RcvdStream.Free;
        Exit;
    end;

RcvdStream.Seek(0,0);
google.LoadFromStream(RcvdStream);
RcvdStream.Free;
 broj:=broj+8;
ParseGoogleApi;
end;
end;

procedure TGoogle.ParseGoogleApi;
var Pos: integer;
    sText: string;
begin
Buffer:= TStringList.Create;
  sText := ExtractText(google.Text, '"url":"', '","visibleUrl"', 1, Pos);
  while sText <> '' do
  begin
    buffer.Add(sText);

    sText := ExtractText(google.Text, '"url":"', '","visibleUrl"', Pos, Pos);
  end;
end;


procedure TGoogle.Execute;
var
  CurrentNum: integer;
  i:integer;

begin

  CurrentNum := Broj;
  while not terminated do
  begin
  skinisors;
      EnterCriticalSection(Form1.StringSection);
      for i:=0 to 5 do                        begin
      Form1.StringBuf.Add(buffer.strings[i]);
      end;
      LeaveCriticalSection(Form1.StringSection);
      PostMessage(Form1.Handle, WM_DATA_IN_BUF, 0, 0);

    end;


end;
end.
```

So I want to know how can I stop the thread when page timeouts or if user gets disconnected etc..  so that thread can be terminated properly.

I want to start 3 instances of this thread and every instance should access critical section take one link ex link[i] where i is integer value that is incremented by thread which has ownership over critical section at that moment. Thanks

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com. SO is for broken code.

Comment: Post a specific problem and a relevant snippet of code

Comment: Formatting of this code is definitely broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your thread a constructor, and in that constructor set `FreeOnTerminate := True;`.

In the thread's execute method you can then call `Terminate;` on page timeout or disconnection.

Comment: Can you explain why this would be an improvement?

Comment: It was a response to the question element `So I want to know how can I stop the thread when page timeouts or if user gets disconnected etc.. so that thread can be terminated properly.`

Comment: But why FreeOnTerminate? Seems to offer no advantage to me.

Comment: If you set FreeOnTerminate you can call Terminate within the thread and it'll be freed. If not, you need to maintain an external pointer and free the thread explicitly or the application will have a memory leak.

Comment: And if you don't maintain a reference to the thread, you can't join it at shutdown. Thus you  might terminate the app whilst holding a shared resource like a mutex. Better to keep the reference and call Free explicitly. In my view FreeOnTerminate is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Agreed. You don't need to use `FreeOnTerminate` to have a self-freeing thread. You can use the thread's `OnTerminate` event to call `PostMessage()` or `PostThreadMessage()` to post a custom message to the main message queue, and then have the message handler free the thread instance. That is much safer than using `FreeOnTerminate` and gives you control over the lifetime of the thread while still being able to react to premature terminations.